# Python, how to set log formatting for jsonPayload

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-logging

I'm trying to write a JSON format data log to Cloud logging from Google cloud run.
but when I check my log in Cloud logging, my data log is in the message field in jsonPayload, as a string type.

like,

```
jsonPayload: {
  message: "{"test": "testing"}"
  python_logger: "cloudLogger"
}
```

but, what I expected,

```
jsonPayload: {
  test: "testing"
}
```

This is the code I tried,

```
client = google.cloud.logging.Client()
handler = CloudLoggingHandler(client, name="test")
cloud_logger = logging.getLogger('cloudLogger')
cloud_logger.setLvel(logging.INFO)
cloud_logger.addHandler(handler)
cloud_logger.info(json.dumps({"test": "testing"})
```

For the change the format for the jsonPayload, I think I might need to set a formatter, and I tried some samples from the web, but no luck.

How can I make it the jsonPayload shows exactly my JSON formatted data?

Comment: It seems like google cloud logging(python) doesn't not support Json format log data?

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem with cloud functions. I was using `python3.7`, used multiple client logging libraries and stackdriver was still showing it as text as the python was printing it in string format.

Ended up upgrading python to `v3.8`, this solved the issue.

Comment: I'm testing with python:3.9-slim image